# Why one free dimension when passing arrays as parameter?

Tags: c, arrays, free, dimension

i came across something quite odd(for me at least), while i was reading a C tutorial:

```
void foo(char arr[]){

}


void main(){

  char old_buffer[100];

  foo(old_buffer);           //Working??!
  char arr2[] = old_buffer;  //Error!


}
```

The line with the error comment is clear to me, old_buffer is treated like an address so this can't work because the array is missing information how much memory should be allocated. But why is this working in the head of a function?
Thanks for your support :)

Comment: Do you mean, why is it working in `void foo(char arr[])`?

Comment: `char *arr2 = old_buffer` and `char *arr2[] = {old_buffer};` both work...

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: Works in which sense? I get `initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast`.

Comment: @alk I'm not getting that warning…  they can't both be named `arr2` in the same function, of course...

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: Hu -I read and tested `char arr2[] = {old_buffer};` As it's the 3rd misread for tonight I'll go to bed ... sry anyway.

Comment: hey guys thanks so far, using an pointer would be an option but thats not what i wanted to know, please check the acepted answer for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The line with the error comment is clear to me, old_buffer is treated like an address so this can't work because the array is missing information how much memory should be allocated.

That's close, but it's not exactly what's happening: the line with the error is not syntactically correct - if you change it to

```
char *arr2 = old_buffer;
```

it will work. However, this would not be an array, it would be a pointer. It would allow array-like access, but it would not give you the correct value in the `sizeof`.

> But why is this working in the head of a function?

Because when you pass an array to a function, the size is always ignored. It is said that the array *decays* to a pointer. In other words, your declaration is identical to this:

```
void foo(char *arr)
```

Comment: True, but why can i write it both ways when declaring a function(head)? Even though (array = pointer) does not work inside a function(body)?

Comment: @user2352375 That's something that the writers of the original C specification have allowed, and that has not changed since (actually, they allowed something that was very close to today's syntax, because parameters were declared outside function's header, but the empty brackets were there back in the K&R's version of the language). They never allowed it for locals and statics, though, only for function parameters.

Comment: @user2352375 If I were you I'd clear any preconceived notions of how you think C works. Writing `arr[]` in a function declaration is different than writing `arr[]` when defining a variable. When arrays are passed to functions, a pointer to the first element in the array is passed. It turns out that `arr[]` and `*arr` in a function declaration are identical.

Comment: Ok i think i get it, so it's a inconsistency of style and the "array" arr in this case is really the same as a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

`old_buffer` is the address of `old_buffer[0]`, that is, it is `&old_buffer[0]`.  `char arr[]` is equivalent to `char *arr`.

Answer (score 0):

the array in c/c++ work as list of sequential pointers in MEM.
the array name is variable that hold the address of first element in array.
when we use the index to reach a value that stored at this index location 
the compiler know that, the value is stored in MEM location that equals to
the address stored in array name added by index value .
Ex :

```
A[0] ='v'
A = 0x000000
A[4] = 'c'

//it is location at  0x000000 + 4
//so the
 &A[4] = 0x000004
```

.

char *arr2 = old_buffer; will be work at your code , and you can deal with arr2 as an array
because it hold address of first element of pre-located  array in MEM .
this compiler way is the reason that get your code to work in the head of a function .